# deriving a templated class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

I have a templated base class which follows:

```
template<class scalar_type, template<typename > class functor>
class convex_opt{ ..
};
```

How to derive a class from this templated class?

Comment: That's not a class. It's a class template. It doesn't become a class until the template parameters are filled in. `convex_opt<Foo, Bar>` is a class and can be derived from. `convex_opt` in itself is nothing more than a template for constructing classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class scalar_type, template<typename > class functor>
class derived : public convex_opt<scalar_type, functor> {
 ...
```

?